# How to filter and display matched hashtag words

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new currently working with REACT NATIVE, and i have problem with filtering array.

so i have pressHashtag and getHashtagResult function.

`pressHashTag`

```
  pressHashtag(ht, id, pid) {
    let self = this;

    global.fromHashtag = true;

    global.socket.off('timelineposts');

    self.setState(
      {
        // timelineData: [],
        // loadingOpacity: 1,
        // tableOpacity: 0,
      },
      () => {
        for (var i = 0; i < global.searchFields.length; i++) {
          if (global.searchFields[i].db_name == 'tag_name') {
            global.searchFields[i].value = ht.replace('#', '');

            result = global.searchFields[i].value;

            Storage.retrieveData().then(data => {
              data.searchSettings = global.searchFields;
              
              Storage.storeData(data).then(() => {
                self.getHashtagResults(result, id, pid);
              });
            });

            break;
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

`getHashtagResult`

```
getHashtagResults(res, userid, post_id) {
    let self = this;

    this.setState(
      {
        showLoading: true,
      },
      () => {
        global.previousPage = global.currentPage;
        global.currentPage = 'Timeline';

        global.socket.on('profile', function (ret1) {
          global.socket.off('profile');

          global.userProfile = ret1;

          let params = {};

          for (var i = 0; i < global.searchFields.length; i++) {
            params[global.searchFields[i].db_name] = '0';
          }

          params['locale'] = global.locale;
          params['month'] = 3;
          params['year'] = 2019;
          params['offset'] = 0;
          params['size'] = 15;

          params['userid'] = userid;
          params['requestor'] = global.user_id;

          params['uuid'] = global.deviceid;
          params['tagname'] = res;


          global.socket.off('userposts');
          global.socket.on('userposts', function (ret2) {
            global.socket.off('userposts');

// alert(JSON.stringify(ret2))
            global.userPosts = ret2;

            global.userProfileParams = params;

            global.selectedPostPostId = post_id;
     

            self.setState(
              {
                showLoading: false,
              },
              () => {
                global.GLComponent.gotoHashtagViewer();
              },
            );
          });

          global.socket.emit('userposts', params);
        });

        let params = {
          uuid: global.deviceid,
          locale: global.locale,
          userid: userid,
          requestor: global.user_id,
        };

        global.socket.emit('profile', params);
      },
    );
  }
```

so the problem was when i click #happy posted my user1 i getting the result all the post of user1 even its not matched to #happy.

please explain as much as you can because im not good with javascript. im just only a beginner and trying to explore and gain more knowledge. Thank you in advance.

already tried to make filter function, but i didn't know how to use it properly

Comment: Please format code as code, not as a quote. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting